# Is there a way to update the DOM with the user-submitted value of a textarea similar to contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I just need the textarea's html markup in the DOM to reflect the value of the user input. (Edit:  the user types something and it shows up when you hit "inspect element")

A contenteditable div was working fine but now it appears I'll need a textarea after all.  Anybody know a way of doing this with javascript or html5?

Comment: Do you need the text area to be gone and replaced with the html markup? or do you need the html to be placed elsewhere in the dom?

Comment: No, I just need the DOM updated so I can grab it and use it for something else.  A normal textarea doesn't update it's html when a user types something in it, whatever he types will be lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess something like this will help you.
Its using pure javascript and html5 data-value attribute:

```
  <textarea id="myTextArea" onkeyup="this.setAttribute('data-value', this.value);" data-value=""></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work using text() function to escape the html from the user input :

```
$('textarea').on( 'blur' , function() 
{
    var textarea = $( this );
    textarea.next('span').text( textarea.val() );
});
```

with the following markup :

```
<textarea></textarea>
<span></span>​
```

The demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/UDfmm/

EDIT : If you want to keep the line breaks then do this

```
$('textarea').on( 'blur' , function() 
{
    var textarea = $( this );
    var span = textarea.next('span');

    var content = span.text( textarea.val() ).html();
    var content_with_br = content.replace(/\n\r?/g, "<br />");

    span.html( content_with_br );

});
```

Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/UDfmm/3/

Comment: This was close but I was having trouble with the line breaks!